# Angular 2 then promise

Tags: angular, promise

I am doing the Angular 2 tutorial with the Hero App. I am at the Http part of the tutorial. ([link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html))

There is a call to the server with the following method in hero.service.ts

```
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data)
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And then I'm trying to use the returned data in heroes.components.ts below but I'm not able to implement the then function correctly. I am getting this console error

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this is null

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

title = 'Tour of Heroes';
heroes: Hero[];
selectedHero: Hero;

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private heroService: HeroService) { }

getHeroes() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(function(value) {
        //SUCCESS
        console.log(value);  //this is working
        this.heroes = value; //this is not working
        console.log("I am inside then SUCCESS")
        console.log(title);
        console.log(this.heroes);

    }, function(error) {
        //FAILURE
        console.log(error);
    })

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
}
```

Do you know why I can't console.log *this.heroes* and *title* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider fat arrow notation to avoid **scope** conflicts. In your case, *this* does not point to the class instance but to the sucesscallback of your promise instead.

```
getHeroes() {
    let instance : HeroesComponent = this;
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then((value) => {
        //SUCCESS
        console.log(value); 
        this.heroes = value; 
        console.log("I am inside then SUCCESS")
        console.log(this.title);
        console.log(this.heroes);

    }, (error) => {
        //FAILURE
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a **scope issue**, in **Typescript** there's a lot of scope issues when passing code to jquery, or other javascript APIs and, in your case, with lambda functions.
To solve that problem you need to **save the scope in a variable**:

```
getHeroes() {
    let instance : HeroesComponent = this;
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(function(value) {
        //SUCCESS
        console.log(value);  //this is working
        instance.heroes = value; //this now works
        console.log("I am inside then SUCCESS")
        console.log(title);
        console.log(instance.heroes);

    }, function(error) {
        //FAILURE
        console.log(error);
    })

}
```

**A very important note**:
Don't use **_this** to save your scope, because it's a **reserved keyword** used by Typescript to do the same thing but automatically, that unfortunatelly not work in the commented cases.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your answers. It was a scope issue.

> You might want to consider fat arrow notation to avoid scope
>   conflicts. In your case, this does not point to the class instance but
>   to the sucesscallback of your promise instead.

I used the fat arrow notation and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into some scoping issues... the this that it is looking up isn't the this you think it is. try somehting like this:

```
getHeroes() {
    let that = this; // use that now in all sub functions
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(function(value) {
        //SUCCESS
        console.log(value);  //this is working
        this.heroes = value; //this is not working
        console.log("I am inside then SUCCESS")
        console.log(that.title);
        console.log(that.heroes);

    }, function(error) {
        //FAILURE
        console.log(error);
    })

}
```